Could it be true that $f_n \to f$ in $H^{-1}$ implies the PDE solutions $u_n \to u$ in $L^\infty(\Omega)$ for dimensions $\leq 3$?
Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n \leq 3$.
Let $u_n \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ be the weak solution of $-\Delta u_n + u_n = f_n$ and $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ be the solution of $-\Delta u + u = f$
Suppose we know that $f_n, f \in L^2(\Omega)$ and $f_n \to f$ in $H^{-1}(\Omega)$. Can it be true that $u_n \to u$ in $L^\infty(\Omega)$?
I have seen a claim that $(-\Delta + 1)^{-1}\colon W^{-1,4}(\Omega) \to L^\infty(\Omega)$ is continuous, and the person who claimed it cites this, but I am dubious (mainly because the reference is in French and the definitions of some maps there are a bit unclear).

The map $f \mapsto u$ is linear and continuos from $L^p(\Omega)$ to $L^\infty(\Omega)$ for $p>n/2$. So if $(f_n)$ is bounded in $L^2$ the $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $L^\infty(\Omega)$. The proof is using the method of your refernce (thm 4.2). Another reference is ``Kinderlehrer, Stampacchia: Variational inequalities''. Since these regularity results are pretty sharp I would not expect that you get the strong convergence without stronger assumptions.

@daw thanks....

The operator $(1-\Delta)^{-1}$ maps $H^{-1}$ to $H^1$ and $L^2$ to $H^2$, hence your assumptions imply $v_n := u_n-u\to 0$ in $H^1$ (and so in $L^2$) and $v_n$ bounded in $H^2$.
The result now follows from the following Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev inequality for $\Omega \subset \Bbb R^d$
$$
\|v_n\|_{L^\infty} \leq C_d \|v_n\|_{L^2}^{1-d/4} \|v_n\|_{H^2}^{d/4}
$$

This answer assumes that $f_n$ is uniformly bounded in $L^2$, but this is not given.

Yes, I supposed it is what the OP meant, but indeed, if it is not true, then the result is only true if $d=1$ (since convergence in $H^1$ still implies convergence in $L^\infty$) and not true at all in dimension $3$ ($u$ could be unbounded)
